# Android Honeycomb has an invereted event.orientation value?

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile, android-3.0-honeycomb

Has anyone else noticed this? I've had to created the below callback to handle orientation change: (oops edit forgot to add) GetAndSetInitialOrientation() is called initially, which as you can see, so than any changes later on are based on that initial value (which I have conditional for). I'm really worried that this isn't safe! Does window.orientation come from Device or browser? I.E will any browser (Opera mini dolphin etc) on Honeycomb act the same or could it just be the native browser?

```
function GetAndSetInitialOrientation() {
    var ori;
    if(Interface.Device.IsHoneyComb()) {
        ori = window.orientation != 0 ? "portrait" : "landscape";
    } else {
        ori = window.orientation == 0 ? "portrait" : "landscape";
    }

    Data.$html.removeClass('landscape portrait').addClass(ori);
}

$(window).bind('orientationchange', function(event) {
    HandleOrientationChange(event);
    RouteBasedOnOrientationSwitch();
});

function HandleOrientationChange(event) { 
    Data.$html.removeClass('landscape portrait');
    if(Interface.Device.IsHoneyComb()) {
        Data.$html.addClass(event.orientation == 'landscape' ? 'portrait' : 'landscape');
    } else {
        Data.$html.addClass(event.orientation);
    }

    Interface.Utility.UpdateHomeLinksURLs();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption that "window.orientation == 0 means portrait" only applies to portrait-based devices.  Most tablets (which maps pretty heavily to Honeycomb / Ice Cream Sandwich) are landscape-based, in which case 0 maps to landscape, and ROTATE_90 and ROTATE_270 map to portrait.

Your current code would work if all devices were either portrait-based OR Honeycomb, mutually exclusively.  However, since there are portrait-based honeycomb devices, AND Ice Cream Sandwich runs on both types of devices, you need a better detection method.

One option is to insert a boolean in your res/values-port/bools.xml and res/values-land/bools.xml that you detect within the parent webview and send to the javascript.  Another would simply be to check screen.width and screen.height, and check which one is larger.  All that said, the most ideal scenario would be, since you're in a webview anyway, to do what you'd do with a web page anyway, and give it a layout that looks good either way, regardless of detected orientation.

Comment: Alexander thank you for that comment very informative! My issue is, I can't just serve the same view for any orientation, unfortunately the app I'm building, for one section, has two entirely different pages which are routed to based on the orientation or a change in orientation.I can't change it as highly corporate and has been through a big design process yadayada. So I need to correctly detect the device orientation as its critical. I'm not sure what you mean with res/values-port/bools.xml , could u elaborate on that method? I'm using HTML/jquerymobile etc is it possible?

Comment: I assumed you were building an Android-based application that a user would download off of market.  If you're building a website, then that option doesn't apply:  I'd check screen.width and screen.height.  If width is larger, it's landscape.  If height is larger, it's portrait.

Comment: yea i should have mentioned that. That is exactly what I've done, thanks for your help mate, have got it working over all android devices including tablets now, and seems to be working without flaw. It really does seem to be the only way around it.